# How to have ubuntu without gnome-screensaver and light-locker

Tags: apt, gnome, dpkg, xscreensaver, light-locker

I do long operations which are steadily getting broken by any power or screen saving utility, so I want to have ubuntu without any power or screensaving programs.

I tried:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge light-locker*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'light-locker-settings' for glob 'light-locker*'
Note, selecting 'light-locker' for glob 'light-locker*'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libgconf-2-4 libgnome-2-0 libgnome-keyring-common
  libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0
  libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libjpeg-turbo-progs liborbit-2-0 xscreensaver
  xscreensaver-data
Suggested packages:
  gconf-defaults-service libbonobo2-bin desktop-base libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra gamin | fam
  gnome-mime-data xfishtank xdaliclock xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra
  fortune qcam | streamer gdm3 | kdm-gdmcompat
Recommended packages:
  perl5
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  light-locker* light-locker-settings* python-psutil*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libgconf-2-4 libgnome-2-0 libgnome-keyring-common
  libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0
  libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libjpeg-turbo-progs liborbit-2-0 xscreensaver
  xscreensaver-data
0 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,861 kB of archives.
After this operation, 23.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

OK, I do not want this. I would like to remove light-locker and xscreensaver totally.

Can you help me? :-)

Thanks

PS. What I have found in the meantime:

less /usr/bin/lxlock
This is the program/script that starts various external lockers.
You can edit it in nano

```
 sudo nano /usr/bin/lxlock
```

and put "exit" on the second row, so you computer will not get locked at any time.

It is not a nice way to do it, but it works.

From the given posibillities (man lxlock), I guess the smallest are suckless-tools.

I got it via this strange command:

```
 sudo apt autoremove light-locker* gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2 gconf2-common libart-2.0-2 libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 gnome-power-manager gnome-screensaver gnome-settings-daemon-schemas libjpeg-turbo-progs libpam-gnome-keyring libupower-glib3 i3lock libev4
```

This installs (sic!) the suckless tools. :-))))

Spurious totally, isn't it? :-)